# How to use alter_column in alembic?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, alembic

I am writing a migration in alembic but seems impossible to me the change the value of server_defaults from something to nothing.

My code:

```
op.alter_column("foo", sa.Column("bar", sa.DateTime(timezone=False), server_default=None, nullable=True))
```

If i check after the migration the default is still NOW()

Answer (score 89):

To rename a column as of Alembic 0.9.5 I had to alter my migration to read as follows:

```
op.alter_column('my_table', 'old_col_name', nullable=False, new_column_name='new_col_name')
```

Comment: Note you also must specify `existing_type` to run `alter_column` command

Comment: It seems that the `existing_type` argument is only mandatory in some circumstances, such as for certain MySQL operations. [The docs](https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/ops.html?highlight=insert#alembic.operations.Operations.alter_column.params.existing_type) have more.

Comment: If you want to support sqlite you'll need to do this in a batch:
`with op.batch_alter_table('my_table', schema=None) as batch_op: batch_op.alter_column('old_col_name', new_column_name='new_col_name')`

Comment: It is not necessary to specify `existing_type` if you use MariaDB , in my case, I modify data type of an existing column by passing the argument `type_`  to `alter_column()` and it works well.

Answer (score 25):

That's not how `op.alter_column()` works.  Pass it arguments about what to change, not a new `sa.Column` instance.

```
op.alter_column('my_table', 'my_column', server_default=None)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
with op.batch_alter_table('my_table', schema=None) as batch_op: batch_op.alter_column('old_col_name', new_column_name='new_col_name')
```

This solution from [Charles](https://stackoverflow.com/users/557406/charles-l) worked like a charm for me.

Update the upgrade function with this and in the downward function add the inverse, new_column_name  -> old_column_name. For my code i commented out the alembic generated code as well.